# References for writing drivers for Windows 7 Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, driver

I need to make a driver for a temperature probe that will connect to my Windows 7 phone.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem but you really need to give us more to work with.  How far have you got so far.  What documentation have you go etc.  After all this is a question and answer forum and not a "Get free work done" forum.

Comment: And how do you connect a probe to WP7?  Duct-tape?

Answer (score 1):

If the temperature probe in question exposes an HTTP interface over WiFi (unlikely as that is), then you can simply connect to it using HTTP (or sockets if you're targetting Mango).

If it requires any other form of connectivity (BT, USB, IR) then you will find no further information on Stack Overflow. Custom device connectivity is not supported by the SDK and information provided to partners is likely under NDA as it is with iOS.

I'd recommend contacting Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Windows Phone OS does not support custom device drivers. That being said, you cannot modify the default driver base with publicly available tools. Even if you decide to go "on the other side" and try to dig through system files, it will be a pain because of the multitude of devices that have their own specific interop rules and I haven't seen a single one that would let you get as low as to access device drivers.